# Equivalence of two implicit functions

Tags: functions

We are given

$$ \phi_{\nu} =  \frac{\nu^3 C}{c^3} e^{-\frac{\nu}{\theta}} \ \ \ \ \ (1)  $$

and

$$ u = \frac{\theta^5}{\nu^2 c^3}\psi \left(\frac{c \theta}{\nu}\right). \ \ \ \ \ (2) $$

Eq.(1) is a function of $ \left( \frac{\nu}{\theta} \right) $; namely,   $ \phi_{\nu} =f_1 \left(\frac{\nu}{\theta}\right)$, but it is also a function, although  another function, of $ \left(\frac{\theta}{\nu} \right) $; namely, $ \Phi_{\nu} = f_2 \left(\frac{\theta}{\nu}\right)$. This is on the one hand.

On the other hand, eq.(2) is a function of $ (\frac{\theta}{\nu} )$; namely, $ u =f_3 \left(\frac{\theta}{\nu}\right) $ but it is also a function, although  another function, of $ \left(\frac{\nu}{\theta}\right) $; namely  $ U =f_4 \left(\frac{\nu}{\theta}\right)$.

The question is, are functions $ f_1 $ and $f_3$ equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Some context is missing from the problem statement, but without further information we can say that equation 2 can not be written in general as a function of $\theta/\nu$, as it contains the $\theta^5/\nu^2$ which messes up the exponents. With the same argument you can say that also equation 1 has the same problem (i.e., can not be written as a function of the same ratio). The conclusion is that functions $f_1$ and $f_3$ do not exist in the form that you prescribed.

Comment: thanks. What do you think if the rhs's are multiplied and divided by proper quantities and the results are sunk, together w/ the const, into the implicit function:

$$\phi_{\nu} = \frac{\nu^3 C}{c^3}e^{-\frac{\nu}{\theta}} =  \frac{\nu^3}{\theta^3} \frac{C}{c^3} \theta^3 f \left(  \frac{\nu}{\theta} \right) = \theta^3  f \left(  \frac{\nu}{\theta} \right) \ \ \ \ \ (1)  $$
and
$$u = \frac{\theta^5}{\nu^2 c^3} \psi\left( \frac{c \theta}{\nu} \right) = \frac{\theta^5 \nu^3}{\nu^2 \nu^3 c^3} f\left(  \frac{\theta}{\nu} \right) = \nu^3 f\left(  \frac{\theta}{\nu} \right)\ \ \ \ \  (2)$$